# Bad Substitution Error Installing NVM within Debian-based Docker image

Tags: linux, bash, docker, debian, dockerfile

I am trying to install nvm on my Docker image. I originally thought that this Docker image was built on Ubuntu, but it is actually built on Debian. I am installing bash to curl NVM, and subsequently install node, but I get a `bad substitution` error:

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker

RUN apk add --update bash \
  && touch /root/.bashrc \
  && curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.2/install.sh | bash \
  && source /root/.bashrc \
  && nvm install node \
  && npm install
```

I think the following error has to do with the line `&& source /root/.bashrc \`

```
=> Downloading nvm as script to '/root/.nvm'

0
=> Appending source string to /root/.bashrc
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm
/bin/sh: /root/.nvm/nvm.sh: line 107: syntax error: bad substitution
ERROR: Service 'docker' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update bash   && touch /root/.bashrc   && curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.2/install.sh | bash   && source /root/.bashrc   && nvm install node   && npm install' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Do you see what is causing this bad substitution error, and is there a more simple way to install nvm on a Debian based Docker image? Thanks for any help.

Comment: First step would be to look at line 107 of /root/.nvm/nvm.sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker image is based out of Alpine Linux. Alpine Linux uses the default shell as `sh`. The error is because of the `sh` vs `bash` incompatibilities.

**Unfortunately, NVM home page has instructions about Alpine Linux, but quite discouraging:**
[nvm on Alpine Linux](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installing-nvm-on-alpine-linux)

After some changes, the final version that made `nvm work with Alpine`:

```
FROM docker
RUN apk add --update bash coreutils ncurses tar gzip nodejs \
  && touch ~/.bashrc \
  && curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.2/install.sh | sh \
  && LINE=$(cat /root/.nvm/nvm.sh | grep -in '{BASH_SOURCE\[0\]}' | awk -F: '{print $1}') \
  && sed -i "${LINE}s/BASH_SOURCE\[0\]\}/BASH_SOURCE\}\$\{0\}/" /root/.nvm/nvm.sh \ 
  && source ~/.bashrc \
  && nvm ls \
  && nvm install node \
  && nvm use --delete-prefix v6.3.1 \
  && npm install
```

A little inconvenience being, you need to use the `nvm use --delete-prefix v6.3.1` every time you need to work with it.

I suggest to try @BMitch's updated answer as well.

Comment: I had to add `RUN rm /usr/bin/node && ln -s /root/.nvm/versions/node/v11.13.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node` after that or it would keep using node `6.7.0`

Answer (score 0):

`FROM docker` bases your image on the "Docker in Docker" Alpine image. Unless you have a special use case that requires Docker in Docker, this probably isn't the base image you want.

If you want a node image, consider using the [premade node image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/). This is based on Debian jessie.

If you need to base your node install another version of [Debian](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/) or [Ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/), you can pick from multiple versions of those images, e.g. `FROM debian:jessie`.

---

Edit: it's pretty easy to add Docker to another image. Here are my Dockerfile entries for a Debian based image (appuser is a user added elsewhere that the container would normally run as, hence the Docker group addition):

```
ARG DOCKER_GID=999
USER root
RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
RUN groupmod -g ${DOCKER_GID} docker && \
    usermod -aG docker appuser
```

Comment: I believe that I actually *do* want Docker in Docker. Ultimately, I need to run `docker` commands from the CL to create containers based off of other images.

Comment: I've updated my answer with steps to add docker to another Debian based image. That will avoid any of the Alpine issues you're experiencing.